# Currency code symbols overview?

Tags: html, unicode, currency

Simple problem, actually. I need an overview of Unicode/HTML Character entity code for all the currencies that are in use. The use is very simple: a list of exchange rates. And yes, for Kazachstan I could just display the text "KZT". say "Kazakhstani tenge" or even use "теңге" or "teñge" but I need to show "₸" instead.
Hey, there it is! :-)
Okay, now I need to know the list for all other currency symbols in HTML! [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbols) provides a good list, but is this a complete list? Is it correct? And what are their codes for HTML usage?

Comment: Found http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf which is practical. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode has a category for currency symbols: "Sc", and then process the [Unicode Character database](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) for code points in that category.

There is a single block of [currency symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf), but various currency symbols (including "$" and "£", latter is Pound sign, in the block there is a separate Lira sign) were encoded before this block was created.

(Also, if the currency's symbol is recently adopted – like that new IRP sign – it might not be in Unicode yet.)

Finally, glyph inclusion in common typefaces is another issue…

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this site](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). Select "Currency Symbols" to see a list of all available currency symbols. To display the majority of them in HTML, you'll have to use the `&#x....` syntax, as they don't have a specific HTML entity code.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of what Unicode specifically supports, you can take a look into the [code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf). However, that is missing all currency without a special symbol (and $, £ and maybe a few others) or multiple letters (e.g. ლ, лв, Sh.So., etc.). So I guess the Wikipedia list is more exhaustive than the Unicode Standard in that regard.

As for inclusion in HTML, most of them are text. Simply include them directly (assuming that you use Unicode), you can even copy it from Wikipedia. If your document character set isn't Unicode, then **change that, ASAP**. In the meantime you can use the usual `&#x<code point value>;` escape mechanism.

Note however, that there is rarely a need of conveying all the world's currencies in their native abbreviated form to the reader. Also some more obscure ones may not be in the fonts the reader has installed. Bear in mind that many people worldwide are still on Windows XP which has horrible Unicode coverage in its fonts (compared to more recent operating systems).

I have no clue what you're building there, but using the ISO codes for the currency and additionally a symbol where appropriate (i.e. for more commonly-used ones) sounds more reasonable to me. Generally the locales you need to support will be happy to see ₪ instead of ILS, but don't expect to support the whole world equally – that's just a cost nightmare. You don't provide translations in every language of the world, either, do you?

Comment: It's an internal project where HTML is used to generate reports. The report generator is able to render the latest unicode symbols and basically, the use of symbols will be kept at a minimum. But for certain totals, some customers just prefer to see the symbol instead of the code... Newer codes will just be managed from a specific table which links currency codes to the symbol code, if there is any...

Comment: And I have a crazy manager who actually wants the whole project to be translated in as many languages as possible. (About 8 or 9 right now.) It's not as bad as it sounds, since we deliver the software plus resources to partners in other countries. Those partners then do the proper translations.